# How to handle input hidden using v-on:change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am changing value of my cart quantity using two SVG icon(@click). This clicking also changing value of following input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="shoppingCartQty" name="qty" v-on:change="() => (cartItem.qty <=0 ? '' :  cartItem.qty--)" :value="cartItem.qty">
```

On change this code I want to submit my form. but it didn't triggering any event.

```
<div class="orderItem" v-cloak v-for="(cartItem, key, index)  in cart.items">
    <div class="quantity">
        <div class="caret caret-up" v-on:click="cartItem.qty++">
            <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 20 100 100"><polygon points="46.34,39.003 46.34,39.003 24.846,60.499 29.007,64.657 50.502,43.163 71.015,63.677 75.175,59.519 50.502,34.844   "></polygon></svg>
        </div>
        <span v-text="cartItem.qty"></span>
        <form v-on:submit.prevent="updateCart" class="form-inline">
                <input type="hidden" name="rowId" :value="cartItem.rowId">
                <input type="hidden" id="shoppingCartQty" name="qty" v-on:change="() => (cartItem.qty <=0 ? '' :  cartItem.qty--)" :value="cartItem.qty">
        </form>
        <div class="caret caret-down" v-on:click="() => (cartItem.qty <=0 ? '' :  cartItem.qty--)">
            <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 -20 100 100"><polygon points="53.681,60.497 53.681,60.497 75.175,39.001 71.014,34.843 49.519,56.337 29.006,35.823 24.846,39.982   49.519,64.656 "></polygon></svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I submit the form onchange of hidden input which value is coming from for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Creator of vue js says

> v-model doesn't work on hidden input because you 
>      shouldn't be using hidden input when you are using Vue. 
>      Why store state in the DOM when you can store it in JS 
>      directly?

So instead you can create a method and put your logic there and call it after clicking `SVG icon(@click)`

[Resourse Link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1194)

Answer (score 1):

At last found a solution for myself.

First I increment/decrement the the value so it will change in my span tag. then I call `handleQtyChange(++cartItem.qty,cartItem.rowId, $event)` function.

```
<div class="orderItem" v-cloak v-for="(cartItem, key, index)  in cart.items">
        <div class="quantity">
            <div class="caret caret-up" v-on:click="handleQtyChange(++cartItem.qty,cartItem.rowId, $event)" title="ব্যাগে আরও একটি পণ্য যোগ করুণ">
                <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 20 100 100"><polygon points="46.34,39.003 46.34,39.003 24.846,60.499 29.007,64.657 50.502,43.163 71.015,63.677 75.175,59.519 50.502,34.844   "></polygon></svg>
            </div>
            <span v-text="cartItem.qty"></span>
            <div class="caret caret-down" v-on:click="() => (cartItem.qty <=0 ? '' :  handleQtyChange(--cartItem.qty,cartItem.rowId, $event))" title="ব্যাগ থেকে একটি পণ্য বাতিল করুণ">
                <svg version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 -20 100 100"><polygon points="53.681,60.497 53.681,60.497 75.175,39.001 71.014,34.843 49.519,56.337 29.006,35.823 24.846,39.982   49.519,64.656 "></polygon></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```